# mongodb: object field is not being being queried

Tags: mongodb, geojson

I have a field in the database called startLocation.

I have the following document with the startLocation, having description: "Banff, CAN"

[image]

But when I query for the startLocation in the database, nothing shows up. Why so?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've got the query wrong, your query is telling the database you want documents where `startLocation` field matches `{ description: 'Banff, CAN' }` but as you've seen it doesn't match that as it has extra fields.

I think this is the query you are wanting.

```js
{ "startLocation.description" : "Banff, CAN" }
```